# Where is my app on android emulator? I am using Eclipse/ADT

Tags: android, android-emulator, adt

I am a bit stuck with some android development. I am using Eclipse/ADT and created a 2 activity project test.
[image]

Everything build and emulator started but i can not see my application.

[image]

I am very new to this, may be missing something obvious. Any idea where i can see my app on emulator?

---

### EDIT

Sliding worked and i manged to reach test app (project name test so i guess same app name) but i get following on screen.
[image]

I expected, a button and some other stuff as my main.xml is as below.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I&apos;m screen 1 (main.xml)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me to another screen" />
```

Definitely some mistake on my part not  sure what?

My manifest.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AppActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".App2Activity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

My main.xml file is as below.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I&apos;m screen 1 (main.xml)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me to another screen" />
```

Comment: Did you swipe to the side and check the rest of the list?

Comment: Actually i am not able to slide emulator screen. How it should be done? Tried to right click (laptop) mouse but no success

Comment: left click and drag, as if you were touching it with your finger and then moving the finger

Comment: OMG, did you really you really right mouse button ? try to touch(click and keep it there) and slide , that's all

Comment: Project Name is Test so i guess app name should be same.

Comment: Your screen shots are too tiny to be of use, but you do appear to have two xml files, perhaps your program is actually using the other one.

Comment: yes i have 2 xml for 2 classes. AppActivity.java –> main.xml
App2Activity.java –> main2.xml

Comment: Check the xml file for `AppActivity.java` i.e. `main.xml`. Or post ur `main.xml`. Check whether you are setting `main.xml` as your layout in `AppActivity.java`.

Answer (score 2):

As your app name is `Test`, it's definitely in screen2.

Just swipe(drag) the screen from left to right and you should get it.

Hope it helps !!!